# Why input tag flex doesn't work？Overflow layout instead of evenly sizing?

Tags: html, css

Why is the `input` overflowing? Allocate space not equally

I want an input width of 300 / 4 px (Ignore the border
)

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 300px; background: red; padding: 5px;">
  <input style="flex: 1;">
  <input style="flex: 1;">
  <input style="flex: 1;">
  <input style="flex: 1;">
</div>
```

Comment: If you are talking about the border, it is because you have set a width of 300px. Other than that, typing characters in the input field doesn't seem to overflow.

Comment: I want an input width of 300/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input` has its default `min-width` which is `auto` so that reason only flex not able to resize it.

so you have to overwrite it with `min-width:0`.

```css
input {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 300px; background: red; padding: 5px;">
  <input style="flex: 1;">
  <input style="flex: 1;">
  <input style="flex: 1;">
  <input style="flex: 1;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, But don't know why

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 300px; background: red; padding: 5px;">
  <input style="flex: 1; width:0;">
  <input style="flex: 1; width:0;">
  <input style="flex: 1; width:0;">
  <input style="flex: 1; width:0;">
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on FF